# How to implement hive plot for graphs in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, visualization

I'm trying to implement a version of the *hive plot* advocated in [Kryzywinski, *et al.*, 2012]. There are many examples of such graphs on the [author's webpage](http://www.hiveplot.net/).

It would be good enough for me to have three axes. I'm now able to project the coordinates onto three axes and style my graph like this via `VertexCoordinates`:

[image: basic hive]

First of all, is there any way to make edges be arcs and not straight lines?

1. Krzywinski M, Birol I, Jones S, Marra M (2012). *[Hive Plots — Rational Approach to Visualizing Networks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bib/bbr069)*. Briefings in Bioinformatics 13(5), 627-644.

Comment: You mean edges, not vertices, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Graph` you can use `EdgeShapeFunction` to make curved edges.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (
    BezierCurve[{#1[[1]], 
                (#1[[1]] + #1[[2]])/ 2 + {-1, 1}/5 (#1[[1]] - #1[[2]])[[{2, 1}]], 
                 #1[[2]]}] &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In `GraphPlot` you would use `EdgeRenderingFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the built-in `"CurvedArc"` for the option `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -1/2}]]
```

[image]