# Is it possible to draw a curved edge between two vertexes of a graph?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

The following code generates a graph.

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
    {{"i" -> "m", 1}, {"i" -> "...", 1}, {"i" -> "n", 1}, {"m" -> "j", 2}, {"..." -> "j", 2}, {"n" -> "j", 2}}, 
    DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexLabeling -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Switch[#3, 1, {Dashed, Arrow[#1, .1]}, 2, {Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

[image]

My question is that is it possible to draw curves between "i" and each of "m", "...", "n" instead of straight lines, like the red curve below? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: You are already using the `EdgeRenderingFunction` with `Arrow`.  All you need to do is use a function that makes curved lines instead of `Arrow`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the reply. I know there is something like BSplineCurve (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html), but I don't know how to apply it in this situation.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11704/57

Comment: Use the [built-in edge-curving method via the `"EdgeLayout"` option](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81394/89).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can construct a `BezierCurve` by adding two control points to the list of vertex coordinates  for the two vertices (`p[[1]]` and `p[[2]]`) incident to an edge.

In the following function `bC` with three arguments (`{t1,t2,t3}`), the two additional points are obtained by taking two points on the line joining the two vertex coordinates, `t1 p[[1]] + (1-t1) p[[2]]` and `t2 p[[1]] + (1-t2) p[[2]]` where `0<= t1, t2 <=1`, and adding to these points `{0,t3}` or `{t3,0}` to ensure that the resulting four points are not collinear. The default values for the three arguments are `{t1,t2,t3}= {1/3,2/3,1/3}`.

```
ClearAll[bC]
bC[t1_:(1/3),t2_:(2/3), t3_:(1/3)]:= With[{p=#}, 
    BezierCurve[{p[[1]],
                 t1 p[[1]]+(1-t1)p[[2]]+If[p[[1,1]]==p[[2,1]],{t3,0},{0,t3}],
                 t2 p[[1]]+(1-t2)p[[2]]-If[p[[1,1]]==p[[2,1]],{t3,0},{0,t3}],
                 p[[2]]}]]&;

LayeredGraphPlot[ {{"i" -> "m", 1}, {"i" -> "...", 1}, {"i" -> "n", 1}, 
                   {"m" -> "j", 2}, {"..." -> "j", 2}, {"n" -> "j", 2}}, 
    DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Switch[#3, 1, {Dashed,Arrow[bC[][#],.1]}, 2, {Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you reopen this question, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I was puzzling over why this q/a was reopened and appeared with a "modified by kguler" tag. I must have inadvertently clicked the reopen button. Sorry.

Comment: That's okay.  It just surprised me as I didn't see any precipitating comments or recent edits.  Why don't you close it now?  I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34177/121) was the previous duplicate if I am reading the timeline correctly.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, how come my accidental click made the previous close votes and links disappear?

Comment: You have the Gold tag badge for `plotting` (and `list-manipulation`) which gives you moderator-like single vote power to close (and apparently reopen) duplicates in this tag.  Use it wisely. :-)   (*Possible duplicate:* comments are automatically deleted when the close occurs.)

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. I wasn't aware of the badges/power relation.

Comment: Full details here: [(231212)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/)